# Insert CSS block and HTML block at the top of body using Reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I insert CSS block and HTML block at the top of the body using Apache reverse proxy.

The idea is that I can insert a (global) menu at the top of all our web apps for easy access.

Comment: Personally, I think it would be easier to append a javascript fragement after, that would insert your css/html in the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out how to do this.

I used mod_substitute and mod_include.

This site has the details 
http://bemasc.net/wordpress/2010/06/24/how-to-not-use-mod_layout/

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good idea. Your users wouldn't be able to trust you, in the sense that you can ADD CODE TO THEIR SITES. You could theoretically add keylogger scripts or something to the site, and so if you're going to be doing this, make it like a codeen server, where all new users are greeted with a welcome message.

Comment: this server is only for internal use.